# Gson deserialising reddit comments API response on android

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, android-json

I am building a reddit client on android, using Retrofit and Gson to make the API requests. I made a request to retrieve the comments for a post

> https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/68pxct/black_out_panels_with_a_twist/.json

While deserialising the response I ran into an issue, The response has a field `children` which returns a `List<CustomObject>` at times and a `List<String>` other times.

I tried multiple options, using a `JsonAdapter` with a custom `JsonDeserializer`, that didn't work, Then tried using it with a `TypeAdapter`, still didn't work.

My field looks like this,

```
@Expose
@JsonAdapter(CustomDeserializer.class)
private List<T> children;
```

In both those cases I hit a class not found exception for the class that i was using with generics. I had break points in the Deserializer it did not even start executing the code. Commenting the @JsonAdapter annotation caused the class not found exception to go away.

I then tried to receive the params into a generic `JsonArray` type but still hit an error

```
@Expose
private JsonArray children;
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 210200 path $[1].data.children[12].data.replies

Why am I not able to convert it to a JsonArray. I thought that should work irrespective of what the inner type is.

Ideally I'd like to get the JsonAdapter method working.

EDIT:

The reason converting it to JsonArry did not work was because there was another field (`replies`) which also returned multiple data types. It should have been obvious looking at the error, I guess it was past my bedtime. So converting the fields to JsonArray and JsonObject worked.

It has also been suggested that generics do not play well with the JsonAdapter annotation, I'll test out the other solutions and update back.

Comment: The `replies` in your data starts with a quote in the JSON, and is not an object `{}`

Comment: You can search the JSON for `"replies": ""`

Comment: @cricket_007 That's true, replies do start that way. But since I'm deserialising the children object as a JsonArray that shouldn't matter?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you try making a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `<T>` for it, because Gson cannot retrieve enough type information for deeply nested subobjects. What you could do is a sort of alignment that would align both "custom objects" and strings together so that you can easily control the these two types.

Assume you might have something like this:

```java
// Not an interface by design: it's most likely there is just two known data types
abstract class Element {

    // So we can control they instantiation
    private Element() {
    }

    // ... any convenient code, visitor pattern stuff here, etc ..

    static Element reference(final String reference) {
        return new ReferenceElement(reference);
    }

    static final class DataElement
            extends Element {

        final String kind = null;
        final Data data = null;

        // Gson does requires neither constructors nor making them non-private
        private DataElement() {
        }

    }

    // This is a special wrapper because we cannot make java.util.String to be a subclass of the Element class
    // Additionally, you can add more methods if necessary
    static final class ReferenceElement
            extends Element {

        final String reference;

        // But anyway, control the way it's instantiated within the enclosing class
        private ReferenceElement(final String reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }

    }

}
```

Since I'm not familiar with the Reddit API, I'm assuming it may be mapped with the following class for particular responses:

```java
final class Data {

    final List<Element> children = null;
    final Element replies = null;

}
```

```java
final class ElementTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // Effectively a singleton, no state, fully thread-safe, etc    
    private static final TypeAdapterFactory elementTypeAdapterFactory = new ElementTypeAdapterFactory();

    private static final TypeToken<DataElement> dateElementTypeToken = new TypeToken<DataElement>() {
    };

    private ElementTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    // So just return the single instance and hide away the way it's instantiated
    static TypeAdapterFactory getElementTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return elementTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Not the Element class?
        if ( !Element.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // Then just let Gson pick up the next best type adapter
            return null;
        }
        //
        final TypeAdapter<DataElement> dataElementTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, dateElementTypeToken);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new ElementTypeAdapter(dataElementTypeAdapter);
        return typeAdapter.nullSafe();
    }

    private static final class ElementTypeAdapter
            extends TypeAdapter<Element> {

        private final TypeAdapter<DataElement> dataTypeAdapter;

        private ElementTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<DataElement> dataTypeAdapter) {
            this.dataTypeAdapter = dataTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Element value)
                throws IOException {
            if ( value instanceof DataElement ) {
                dataTypeAdapter.write(out, (DataElement) value);
            } else if ( value instanceof ReferenceElement ) {
                out.value(((ReferenceElement) value).reference);
            } else {
                // null-protection is configured with .nullSafe() above
                throw new AssertionError(value.getClass());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Element read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            final JsonToken token = in.peek();
            switch ( token ) {
            case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                return dataTypeAdapter.read(in);
            case STRING:
                return reference(in.nextString());
            case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            case END_ARRAY:
            case END_OBJECT:
            case NAME:
            case NUMBER:
            case BOOLEAN:
            case NULL: // null-protection is configured with .nullSafe() above
            case END_DOCUMENT:
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Cannot parse " + token + " at " + in);
            default:
                // If someday there are more tokens...
                throw new AssertionError(token);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now put this all together:

```java
    private static final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Element>>() {
    }.getType();

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getElementTypeAdapterFactory())
            .create();

    public static void main(final String... args)
            throws IOException {
        try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43764362.class, "reddit.json") ) {
            final List<Element> elements = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
            dump(elements);
        }
    }

    private static void dump(final Iterable<Element> abstractElements) {
        dump(abstractElements, 0);
    }

    private static void dump(final Iterable<Element> abstractElements, final int level) {
        final String tab = repeat(".", level);
        for ( final Element e : abstractElements ) {
            if ( e instanceof DataElement ) {
                final DataElement dataElement = (DataElement) e;
                System.out.print(tab);
                System.out.print("DATA=");
                System.out.println(dataElement.kind);
                if ( dataElement.data.children != null ) {
                    dump(dataElement.data.children, level + 1);
                }
                if ( dataElement.data.replies != null ) {
                    final Element replies = dataElement.data.replies;
                    if ( dataElement.data.replies instanceof DataElement ) {
                        dump(((DataElement) replies).data.children, level + 1);
                    } else if ( dataElement.data.replies instanceof ReferenceElement ) {
                        System.out.print(tab);
                        System.out.print("REF=");
                        System.out.println(((ReferenceElement) dataElement.data.replies).reference);
                    } else {
                        throw new AssertionError(replies.getClass());
                    }
                }
            } else if ( e instanceof ReferenceElement ) {
                System.out.print(tab);
                System.out.print("REF=");
                System.out.println(((ReferenceElement) e).reference);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(e));
            }
        }
    }
```

Output excerpt from the current response:

> DATA=Listing
>   .DATA=t3
>   DATA=Listing
>   .DATA=t1
>   ..DATA=t1
>   ...DATA=t1
>   ....DATA=t1
>   .....DATA=t1
>   ......DATA=t1
>   .......DATA=more
>   ........REF=dh0x8h5
>   .....DATA=more
>   ......REF=dh11148
>   ......REF=dh19yft
>
> ..REF=dh0pcjh
>   ..REF=dh0n73y
>   ..REF=dh0kp1r
>   ..REF=dh0mg9c
>   ..REF=dh0i6z5
>   ..REF=dh0inc3
>   ..REF=dh0oyc4
>   ..REF=dh0phb0
>   ..REF=dh0ln22
>   ..REF=dh0wjqa
>   ..REF=dh0q48s
>   ..REF=dh0tfjl
>   ..REF=dh0kauq
>   ..REF=dh0rxtf
>   ..REF=dh0led3

Comment: Thanks. Your solution looks perfect for what I need. I changed both the fields to JsonObject and JsonArray types and it works for now, I'll test this out today.